# React-Native - How to make an interactive chart

Tags: typescript, react-native, charts

I'm trying to create a LineChart in React-Native that has the following features:

- Tap on the graph and add a marker in the coordinate where I tapped;
- Translate the marker on the graph and change its values dynamically;
- Finally, add these values to an array;

I'm using ReactNative with Typescript, I've tried several libraries but none have these features.

Does anyone have an idea how to do such a thing?

this should be the final result, in this chart, I can add a new marker(the green dots) tapping on it, and translate them

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple libraries for charts in react native.

- [react-native-charts-wrapper](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper)
- [react-native-chart-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit)

You can use these libraries with minimum customization to achieve your design.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried this libraries but they don't have the feature to make an interactive chart and add a marker on the graph dynamically and translate it :(

Comment: Gi @DomenicoVotta can you explain what do you mean by interactive? to my knowledge these charts support interaction and click events, plus we can definitely add values to chart dynamically

Comment: so I would to click in a particular point on the chart, and add a marker (a dot) that has the values of that point of the chart, and then, if I click on the dot I can move it on the chart on the axis .